# What are the ways to secure Azure functions

Tags: c#, azure, security, azure-functions, azure-security

I have written 5 Azure functions in Azure Portal using c#.

Below are the steps to install my application:-

- Copy deployment scripts to the Edge node of the cluster
- Deployment
  scripts to do the following

  - Call Azure functions to do get my application builds from WASB.
  - Install my application on Edge node
  - Call Azure functions to do some updation.

Above process will be executed on the Customer Edge node.

The authorization using “[keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#keys)” described here is just to provide another layer of API key authorization and is not applicable when my script needs to be called by a public client (like edge node) since it is discover-able there.

What are the best ways to secure the Azure Functions in my scenario?

Comment: Consider "stored procedure"-like flow. Public function behaves as webhook (validates data and pushes it off to private azure function/queue). Also: `Never trust, always verify[/sanitize]`. Between the two, can bridge some gaps without having to fully invest into key exchanges. Some things though should require key (`delete_user()` etc.)

Answer (score 12):

By default azure functions are public . So you deploy them and the endpoint is available publicly via the address on the function. As you mentioned , you can set function level access, which means you need to pass an access key. So they are kind if protected.

There are some other options though:

You can build functions inside a vnet using the azure environment service.  But for this you pay good money and you have to use the service plan version of azure functions.

I have combined [API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/) with functions. API Management is a way to expose your apis to consumers but maintain lots of control over the usage. The Api Management component does not prevent the public azure address being available but I have implemented pattern in code which checks for a special token which is appended to a http request as part of the app management  pass-through. Or alternatively you can set IP restrictions on the Function app to allow traffic only from the API Management endpoint.  (IP Address)   So effectively you can only go to the function via the app management.

Just a note on the above, Azure portal has removed the ability to set IP restrictions  via the standard functions network tab. So you need to go into the resource explorer and set the IP restrictions manually in the web config section.

Lastly , you could set up an oauth server and validate the token in the function or in an api management component or both.

Comment: Maybe you can include the link to the official documentation which also outlines the available options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#secure-an-http-endpoint-in-production

Answer (score 4):

AZURE ASE (App Service Environment) is way too expensive for only 5 functions. You can secure the functions by adding application gateway and whitelist the IP address of the Application gateway in the function. You can find more details here:
[Whitelisting in Azure Functions](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/whitelisting-azure-functions-mike-douglas)

This is all in addition to having token based or AAD based authentication and authorization (like 'Noel' mentioned in the previous reply).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to protect your Azure Functions is by AAD or authentication server you trust.
If that is not feasible, probably because you are consuming these functions from Console or App does not support the authorization code flow, or used by users who do not exist in your AAD, then use APIM.
The technique provided by @Noel below is powerful and it is needed to restrict access to your functions only from APIM.(**Functions should not be anonymous, and there is no need to have any authorization code aside from the APIM code**)
Now think how to protect the APIM.
You have multiple options, but probably you can consider the client certificate as means of proper authentication.
At the end, consumers need to have something to authenticate them (password, certificate, device, or anything) .. So setting a policy to check and existence of a certificate and finding a way to validate that certificate can help protecting your APIM.
The question now becomes about protecting the APIM and here you have many policy-based options.
Hope that helps. (Also don't forget to consider other solutions provided by Noel above)